# Two queries vs select all

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using Mysql and php.

This is my table structure:=

```
+----+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| id | no_of_replies | reply1 | reply2 | reply3 | reply4 | reply5 | reply6 |
+----+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| -- | --            |        | --     | --     | --     | --     | --     |
+----+---------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

There are max six replies a user can give for a question.Most of the time user is giving 4-5 replies.i store the number of replies(no_of_replies) and all the replies(reply1,reply2,...).
Mostly the reply5 and reply6 are NULL.

so when displaying data I have 2 options.

option1:-
do single query and get all responses-

```
SELECT * FROM `responses` WHERE `id`='xyz'
```

option2:-
do 2 queries and get required responses.

```
SELECT `no_of_repies` FROM `responses` WHERE `id`='xyz'
```

if result is 3

SELECT `reply1`,`reply2`,`reply3` FROM `responses` WHERE `id`='XYZ'

NOTE:=
I am asking this because this table is going to be used very often and needs to quickly give responses.

Comment: Why would you like to have a query that will return an unknown number of columns ? How will you programmatically process the result? The overhead of getting the empty/null results are negligable

Comment: Using RDMS would ease up your job. Instead of having `reply1, reply2...`, put those in a separate table. Then you won't have to worry about `no_of_replies`. Simply `SELECT reply_text FROM table2 WHERE foreign_key = primary_key`

Comment: Is `id` the userid or questionid - and how do you know the other one?

Comment: @asprin I am not able to figure out how to put these columns in seperate table and how will it solve the problem

Comment: @sid And how do you know which question these replies belong to?

Comment: @kingkero have a separate table for questions having this id as foreign key between these tables

Answer (score 2):

You should read about database normalization.In your case i would do it like this :

```
tabel
---------------------------------
id    reply     date   questinID
```

to get the amount of replies for 1 person for 1 question

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabel WHERE id=userid AND questionID=questionid;
```

to get the replies for 1 question for 1 user:

```
SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE id=userid AND questionID=questinid ORDER BY date;
```